# PHPWord to PDF not able to load library

Tags: php, tcpdf, dompdf, phpword

I have been trying all day to get this to work. Right now I am able to save the document as .docx file but I wanted to be able to save the document as PDF I have tried with DOMPDF and TCPDF but I keep getting error 'Unable to load PDF Library' I confirmed the path is correct. Am I missing something? thank you for your help

```
$rendererName = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::PDF_RENDERER_TCPDF;
$rendererLibrary = 'tcpdf.php';
$rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__) .'/plugins/tcpdf/' . $rendererLibrary;

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererName,$rendererLibraryPath);

$document->saveAs('temp.docx'); // Save to temp file
$test = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load('temp.docx'); // Read the temp file
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($test, 'PDF');
$xmlWriter->save('result.pdf');  // Save to PDF
unlink('temp.docx'); // Delete the temp file
```

Here is the code that is throwing the error

```
  public function __construct(PhpWord $phpWord)
{
    parent::__construct($phpWord);
    $includeFile = Settings::getPdfRendererPath() . '/' . $this->includeFile;
    if (file_exists($includeFile)) {
        /** @noinspection PhpIncludeInspection Dynamic includes */
        require_once $includeFile;
    } else {
        // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
        // Can't find any test case. Uncomment when found.
        throw new Exception('Unable to load PDF Rendering library');
        // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
    }
}
```

Here is the full error

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Exception\Exception' with message 'Unable to load PDF Rendering library' in 
.../PHPWord/Writer/PDF/AbstractRenderer.php:92 Stack trace: #0 .../PHPWord/Writer/PDF.php(61): PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\PDF\AbstractRenderer->__construct(Object(PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord)) #1 .../PHPWord/IOFactory.php(34): PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\PDF->__construct(Object(PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord)) #2 .../download_report.php(578): PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter(Object(PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord), 'PDF') #3 {main} thrown in .../PHPWord/Writer/PDF/AbstractRenderer.php on line 92

Comment: What line do you get the error at? Does it show? Have you checked the permissions on the tcpdf folder?

Comment: error line AbstractRenderer.php:92 and PDF.php(61) I have not checked permissions what should they be?

Comment: probably 755 is a good way to start for permissions. Though you could, *AS A TEST* set them to 777 just to see if that's the problem then switch it back.

Comment: they were at 755, I changed them to 777 and nothing still the same I'll post the lines of code that's throwing the error

Comment: well, it def has to be the path, because file_exists is failing. var_dump $includeFile the line after you set it. What's the result?

Comment: wow you are correct here is the path plugins/tcpdf/tcpdf.php/tcpdf.php tcpdf.php is twice

Comment: ok I fixed and it's working now. Though there are no images and the tables are all messed up but the PDF got saved so thank you very much!

Comment: great! Good luck w/ the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing al that, I'm guessing the answer is changing:

```
$includeFile = Settings::getPdfRendererPath() . '/' . $this->includeFile;
```

to

```
$includeFile = Settings::getPdfRendererPath();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to send DOMPDF Path in:

```
$domPdfPath = "..vendor/dompdf/dompdf/";
Settings::setPdfRendererName(Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF);
Settings::setPdfRendererPath($domPdfPath); //<---
```

Then in AbstractRerender construct if you echo $this->Include file you should see 'dompdf_config.inc.php'

If you don't have dompdf_config.inc.php file, try to use dompdf 0.6.2

Answer (score 0):

When I print the error to log, I realize it is trying to load the dompdf_config.inc.php from an invalid location. See below.

C:\wamp\www\cccake\app\Vendor\dompdf\dompdf.php/dompdf_config.inc.php\n

Rather than altering the class files of PHPExcel/ PHPWord, it's wise to change the configuration in your view. Ignoring the $rendererLibrary completely in the $rendererLibraryPath fixed my issue. I think the PHPExcel/PHPExcel know how to pick dompdf.php file (tcpdf.php) in your case. Try below code let us know if it doesn't work.

$rendererLibrary = 'tcpdf.php';
$rendererLibraryPath = dirname(**FILE**) .'/plugins/tcpdf';