# PHPWord + dompdf "Unable to load PDF Rendering library" and "dompdf_config.inc.php" problems

Tags: pdf-generation, dompdf, phpword

I'm using PHPWord (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) to generate a Microsoft Word file (.docx) which I save to my system.  This works perfectly and as expected.  I also want to save an Adobe Acrobat version of that file (.pdf) to my system.  For that I'm relying on PHPWord in conjunction with dompdf (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf).  That's where the trouble begins.

My PHP code is the following:

```php
// first, save the completed .docx file that I've generated
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, "Word2007");
$objWriter->save($path_docx);

// second, set PHPWord PDF rendering variables
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath("/var/www/html/vendor/dompdf/dompdf");
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName("DomPDF");

// third, load the .docx file which we just saved above
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($path_docx);  

// fourth, save the new PDF file to the location of choice
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, "PDF");
$xmlWriter->save("/var/www/html/export/my-pdf-version-of-the-file.pdf");
```

When I run the code above I get the following error:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Exception\Exception' with message 'Unable to load PDF Rendering library' in /var/www/html/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/PDF/AbstractRenderer.php:94 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/PDF.php(65): PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\PDF\AbstractRenderer->__construct(Object(PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord)) #1 /var/www/html/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/IOFactory.php(44): PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\PDF->__construct(Object(PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord)) #2 /var/www/html/assets/core/phpword.php(593): PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter(Object(PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord), 'PDF') #3 /var/www/html/export/index.php(94): exportOutline(Array) #4 {main} thrown in **/var/www/html/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/PDF/AbstractRenderer.php** on line **94**

I began searching Google for errors similar to this and came upon this Stack Overflow post: [PHPWord to PDF not able to load library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29834208/phpword-to-pdf-not-able-to-load-library).  They suggested editing some code within the "/var/www/html/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/PDF/AbstractRenderer.php" file.  The code snippet referenced in that post is the following:

```php
public function __construct(PhpWord $phpWord)
{
    parent::__construct($phpWord);
    $includeFile = Settings::getPdfRendererPath() . '/' . $this->includeFile;
    if (file_exists($includeFile)) {
        /** @noinspection PhpIncludeInspection Dynamic includes */
        require_once $includeFile;
    } else {            
        debug($includeFile);
        // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
        // Can't find any test case. Uncomment when found.
        throw new Exception('Unable to load PDF Rendering library');
        // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
    }
}
```

They suggested I get rid of this portion of the code which appears on the 4th line above:

```php
. '/' . $this->includeFile
```

When I implemented that solution, however, it didn't fix my problem.  Frustrated, I then looked at the value generated for $includeFile within that snippet of code.  For me, the value was **"/var/www/html/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php"**.  Once I saw that it was trying to include a file called "dompdf_config.inc.php" I then searched my directory for the file.  It wasn't at the referenced location nor anywhere in my system!

At that point I began searching Google again for that file name and ended up on this Stack Overflow post: [I Can't Find dompdf_config.inc.php or dompdf_config.custom.inc.php for setting "DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED" true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182619/i-cant-find-dompdf-config-inc-php-or-dompdf-config-custom-inc-php-for-setting).  That post suggests that dompdf 0.7.0 no longer relies on that configuration file.  At this point I begin thinking that PHPWord's current version (which I'm using) which relies on dompdf has not been updated to support the current version of dompdf (which I'm using).  I simply don't know.

**My questions:**

1. Can someone confirm if it's true that PHPWord's current version does not play well with dompdf's current version?
2. If the current version of both are supposed to work together, then what am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Thank you in advance for all of your help!

**Note:** I should note that I've included PHPWord and dompdf in my project via composer; so all relevant files are located in "/var/www/html/vendor" as one would expect.  Also, I can't rely on TCPDF nor MPDF (which are alternate PDF rendering engines) because they generate files that don't meet the formatting needs I require for my project.

Comment: Are you specifying dompdf in your composer.json file or letting Composer handle dependencies? The last version of PHPWord does [specify dompdf 0.6.x as a dependency](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/v0.13.0/composer.json).

Comment: I specified it in composer.json which in turn I thought handles required dependencies automatically. No? Note that including  PHPWord in composer.json does not automatically pull down dompdf because it's an optional dependency. Do you think because I have dompdf 0.7.0 installed instead of 0.6.* installed that might be causing the issue? I will try 0.6.* when I'm by my computer later.

Comment: Though dompdf is specified in the `require-dev` property, but that only resolves for the root composer.json file. If no other packages are requiring dompdf and you're specifying the library in your own composer.json you should definitely use 0.6.2.

Comment: I finally got dompdf to work once I specified "0.6.*" in composer.  Unfortunately, the PDF version of the file doesn't include ANY of the formatting I defined in the resulting .docx version generated by PHPWord.  There are no bullets, no indenting, and no coloring styles applied in the PDF.  I think I'm going to just have to buy phpdocx at this point.  Can't believe there's no PDF generator that can respect the styles specified in PHPWord.

Comment: I haven't used the PHPWord library, so I can't say for sure what's going on. Dompdf should be able to handle that type of styling. The reference to the stylesheet may not be accurate based on how dompdf translates the path information.